# Transferring from Samsung to vanilla Android

Tags: data-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s7, nokia-6

I am going from a Samsung Galaxy S7 to Nokia 6. The setup downloaded all of my apps, but none of my files, sms and settings. Of course, I wont get the things I got from Samsung, but there are games I have to start all over and other nuisances. How can I get at least almost everything back?

Comment: Sounds like one of our [ever present questions](/search?q=transfer+data+from+old+phone) (‹ we have a good search engine ;) Please [try with some other keywords](/search?q=migrate+phone+answers%3A1) as well, there should be several good hints. Like: [Is it possible to migrate apps and their data from one unrooted Android phone to another?](/q/88563/16575) // [Transfer everything to new phone?](/q/29669/16575) // [How to transfer SMS message store to new phone](/q/18908/16575) (and also look at the questions linked there in the "related" section).

Comment: Oh.... I see... Thank you! I'll use the search engine onwards :)

Comment: Always glad to help! When you found a solution, please consider either [answering your own question](/help/self-answer) – or, if an existing post fully covers it, let us know to mark yours a duplicate to that. This will help future "seekers" finding it. Good luck!